# How can the user communicate with my python script using the shell?

Tags: python

How can I implement the following in python?

```
#include <iostream>

int main() {
   std::string a; 
   std::cout <<  "What is your name? ";
   std::cin >> a; 
   std::cout << std::endl << "You said: " << a << std::endl;
}
```

Output:

> What is your name? Nick
>
> You said: Nick

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Call

```
name = raw_input('What is your name?')
```

and

```
print 'You said', name
```

Comment: You might want to do "name.rstrip()" or just "name.strip()" to remove whitespace.

Comment: Feel free to post that as an answer and i'll upmod it

Answer (score 3):

Look at the `print` statement and the `raw_input()` function.

Or look at `sys.stdin.read()` and `sys.stdout.write()`.

When using `sys.stdout`, don't forget to flush.

Answer (score 3):

```
print "You said:", raw_input("What is your name? ")
```

EDIT: as Swaroop mentioned, this doesn't work (I'm guessing `raw_input` flushes stdout)

Comment: This would print "You said What is your name?"

Answer (score 1):

The simplest way for python 2.x is

```
var = raw_input()
print var
```

Another way is using the input() function;  n.b. input(), unlike raw_input() expects the input to be a valid python expression.  In most cases you should raw_input() and validate it first.  You can also use

```
import sys
var = sys.stdin.read()
lines = sys.stdin.readlines()
more_lines = [line.strip() for line sys.stdin]

sys.stdout.write(var)
sys.stdout.writelines(lines+more_lines)
# important
sys.stdout.flush()
```

As of python 3.0, however, input() replaces raw_input() and print becomes a function, so

```
var = input()
print(var)
```